Problem with my frontend going to the frontend URL for requests instead of backend. (Flask/React+Vite)
I am developing a web application using Flask for the backend, React with Vite for the frontend, and PostgreSQL as the database. I want to have routes on both the frontend and backend with a prefix of /api. However, when I implement this, the requests are being directed to the frontend URL instead of the intended backend URL.
The only workaround I have found is to remove the /api prefix from the backend routes while keeping it on the frontend routes. With this configuration, I can access the backend endpoints regardless of whether they have the /api prefix or not. The problem only arises when both the frontend and backend routes have the /api prefix.
I would appreciate any help, I'll put some files and Axios requests below.
vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  envDir: '..',
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api\//, '')
      },
      "/search": {
        target: "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/search/, '')
      }
    }
  },
});

Some of my server.py stuff:
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import logging
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env.local')

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URI')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


CORS(app)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

@app.route('/api/')
@app.route('/api/users')
@app.route('/api/search', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/api/history/<ticker>')
@app.route('/api/quote/<ticker>')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)

Axios requests:
const response = await axios.get(`/api/history/${ticker}?interval=${interval}&period=${period}`);

const response = await axios.get(`/api/company/${ticker}`);

const response = await axios.get(`/api/search?q=${input}`);

I have tried using tools like netstat to verify if the backend is listening on the correct port, and it appears to be functioning properly. I can launch the backend server in the browser without any issues. I've also checked my vite.config.js a billion times trying to remove certain parts and see if it works then but nothing works for me. I've also removed the /search proxy sometimes, but that also doesn't work. I've also tried different CORS configurations, where I allow all requests from anywhere but I just stuck with CORS(app) because that's what it seems to do anyway. I've also changed between localhost and 127.0.0.1 with the same issue.
